# How costly is DB data transfer as compared to data storage?

Tags: database, data, resources

I've seen a number of answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151804/3748908), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26566820/3748908), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229919/3748908)) where they state that storage is cheap. So when designing a DB structure, it shouldn't be a main concern, or at least it doesn't rank very high in the list of concerns. What troubles me is that although storing data is very cheap, moving it around, [transferring it between DB and application when querying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32986032/3748908), isn't so much.

Why does this seem to be often neglected? Am I wrong and is it also as unimportant as storage? I mean, how do transferring costs rank in comparison to storage costs?

Comment: Because you usually access only a minuscule amount of your data at a time, but you have to store *all* the data *all* the time.

Comment: What on earth makes you think this is neglected? You have all that juicy data to serve up to the end user and if that process is slow, this often becomes your top priority...

Answer (score 4):

What makes you say it is neglected?

The bandwidth actually matters. A most common consequence is that SQL queries are often tailored to return only a small amount of data. For instance, if you need to display the names of customers who were online during the last month, instead of doing a:

```
select * from `Customers`
```

and filtering the results within the application itself, you'll:

```
select `Name` from `Customers` where `LastVisited` >= @lastVisitFrom
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. What makes me think that is neglected is that I keep reading _storage is cheap_, but I don't so often read _don't use BIGINT when an INT will do because you'll have to transfer extra info every single time_

Comment: @nprensen: beware of premature optimization. Using `tinyint` instead of `int` to store a percentage is just common sense. On the other hand, using `smallint` to store the PKs of the products just because you believe that your e-commerce website will never be too successful and never reach 32 768 products makes little sense. If you have to transfer billions of numbers per hour, the actual type could be a bottleneck; otherwise, there are probably more crucial optimizations to do.

Comment: Also, both storage and network transfers can use compression. Oracle SQL*Net protocol has used compression for many years, which is easily demonstrated but rarely known. When network bandwidth is a concern it could be reduced by ordering the data.